# C# Get higest item using arrays

Tags: c#

I try get higest item from map, but code not working :( Hope guys know more about arrays :)

Error:

```
System.NullReferenceException was caught
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=Game1
  StackTrace:
       in Game1.Map.GetTopItem(Int32 X, Int32 Y) Line 11
       in UserMovedToItem(User User, MapItem MapItem, String Extra)
  InnerException:
```

Code:

```
private MapItem GetTopItem(int X, int Y)
{
    double Height = 0.0;
    MapItem[] TopItem = null;
    foreach (MapItem @class in this.FloorItems.Values)
    {
        if (@class.Int32_0 == X && @class.Int32_1 == Y)
        {
            Height += @class.Height;
            TopItem[Height] = @class;
        }
    }
    return TopItem.Max();
}
```

Comment: Your `MapItem[] TopItem = null` is what's doing it. You never create an array, but you try to access it using `MapItem[Height] = @class`. Also don't use a variable name `@class`. And you also can't index into an array using a `double` (`Height`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You initialize `TopItem` to `null`, and then try to reference it in your `if` block.  It's `null`, there's nothing there to reference.

Why do you need to build an array of the values anyway?  If you're just looking for the highest `Height` value in the data you already have, then just pull it from that data.  Something like this:

```
return this.FloorItems.Values
                      .Where(f => f.Int32_0 == X && f.Int32_1 == Y)
                      .OrderByDescending(f => f.Height)
                      .First();
```

This operates on the existing data, filtering by the X/Y values you're using, sorting it, and returning the first value after the sort.

Or am I misunderstanding what this code is doing?  Admittedly it's *very* difficult to follow given the very non-conventional naming scheme you're using.

Note that this assumes that there is *at least* one value in `this.FloorItems.Values`.  If it's possible for that collection to be empty then you'll want to perform some kind of error check.  How you handle that is up to you, since the method expects to return a value `MapItem`.  You *could* return `null`, but that's a bit of an anti-pattern.  Throwing an exception for invalid data is a common approach.

Answer (score 1):

`TopItem`  shouldn't be null. You should initialize your `MapItem[]` array with the highest length you expect otherwhise use LIST

```
private MapItem GetTopItem(int X, int Y)
{
    double Height = 0.0;
     //here you should initialize your array 
    //MapItem[] TopItem = null;
    List<MapItem> topItems =  new         List<MapItem>(); 
    foreach (MapItem @class in this.FloorItems.Values)
    {
        if (@class.Int32_0 == X && @class.Int32_1 == Y)
        {
            Height += @class.Height;
            //TopItem[Height] = @class;
             topItems.Add(@class); 
        }
    }
    //return TopItem.Max();
     return topItems.Last().Max(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a bit confusing, most notably using `double Height` as an index into your array. I made some assumptions, but this may be what you are looking for.

```
private MapItem GetTopItem(int X, int Y)
{
    return this.FloorItems.Where(item => item.Int32_0 == X && item.Int32_1 == Y)
                          .OrderByDescending(item => item.Height)
                          .FirstOrDefault( );
}
```

This accomplishes the exact same thing succinctly. First it selects the items that match your conditions using the `Where` method. Then, using `OrderByDescending` it orders the items from largest to smallest by using the `item.Height` property. Finally it selects the first item, which should be the largest, using `FirstOrDefault`, and if the collection contains no elements it returns `null`.